# How can I enumerate backwards?

Tags: lists, enumerate

Simple question. I want to use `enumerate` with `\item`, except the numbering goes backwards, e.g. beginning at *n* and ending at 1.

Comment: Good question. The solution will undoubtedly require a second compilation pass.

Comment: `\usepackage{etaremune}` …hehehehe – nice XD

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\reverselabel[1]{%
  \def\theenumi{}%
  \renewcommand\makelabel{\makebox[\dimexpr\labelwidth-3pt\relax][r]{%
    \the\numexpr#1-\value{enumi}+1\relax}}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\reverselabel{10}%
\item \lipsum[4] 
\item text
\item still descending??
\end{enumerate}
Leaving list.
\begin{enumerate}
\reverselabel{3}%
\item New start label 
\item text
\item still descending??
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]